# when npm install or not install devDependencies?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I using npm a few years. But I still don't know when npm install devDependencie and when don't install?

In npm docs, `npm install --production` don't install `devDependencies`.

But in my testing, I init a package, add eslint to dependencies, run `npm install --production`, the eslint's devDependencies still installed? I don't know why?

I want a table to specify when to install or when to skip.

Answer (score 1):

`devDependencies` are dependencies that you only use during local development, including running local tests and running local build tools. `eslint` is a `devDependency` because you only use it for local code linting.

`dependencies` are for dependencies required for your final deliverable project to run. Your project might be an npm module, or a node program, or a bundled Javascript file. If you use Webpack to build your Javascript, but don't include Webpack's source code in your final output, then webpack is a `devDependency`.

This is especially important when publishing an npm node module so that the consumers of your package don't download other packages that are never used.

Comment: For example, I create project called `TestProject` and add `A` package to `dependencies`. `A` package has a `devDependencies` called `B`. Then I run `npm install --production` in project `TestProject`. If `B` package would be installed? Why? Any docs explains that?

Comment: Good answer! But can you specify which npm commands install or not install dependencies in devDependencies?